# Business Intelligence on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 appears as not installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio 017 Environment]

Few days ago I have installed `SSDT` package with `Visual Studio 2017`, `Business Intelligence` environment. I built a solution on SSAS Tabular and when I now want to open it says - Incompatible.
I looked for the `Business Intelligence` Package, trying to create a new `SSAS` `Tabular` project and the BI feature was not available anymore in the list of installed components. This is second time when this happens in the last 3 weeks. The first time I reinstall `SSDT` components. Why is this happening?